# Select component didn't re-render when cell gets new record - Ant Design

Tags: javascript, antd

Currently, I am using Select component as a column in Ant Design table like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX9rY.png)

But I found that although the record has changed, the value shown in "Select" component still is not changed. That means when I change to page 2 or 3, the "Action" column, or what shown in "Select" component in particular, still displays the same values, even thought the record is changed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J3Ns.png)

When I click on to change the value, "Select" works normally & call the API to update the correct record. I have tried to use "shouldCellUpdate" attribute of "Table" component but it didn't work.

Could you please help me solve this problem or give me a suggestion?
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's look like all select components in table are not stateful/controlled components. Make it controlled so when you click on select dropdown, you reset the dropdowns values for new table data